# How to preprocess input for a keras H5 converted model into a pb file

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I successfully converted a Keras H5 model into a Tensorflow pb file but I get totally different result when making a prediction.

In Python I use 2 Keras modules to preprocess the data before feeding the network:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
```

Here is how I preprocess the data in my Python code:

```
# extract the object ROI, convert it from BGR to RGB channel
# ordering, resize it to 224x224, and preprocess it
moving_object = img_orig[startY:endY, startX:endX]
moving_object = cv2.cvtColor(moving_object, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
moving_object = cv2.resize(moving_object, (224, 224))
moving_object = img_to_array(moving_object)
moving_object = preprocess_input(moving_object)
    
objects.append(moving_object)
```

Then I make batch predictions via the Keras predict method:

```
# only make a predictions if at least one object was detected
if len(objects) > 0:
objects = np.array(objects, dtype="float32")
preds = wine_plant_model.predict(objects)
```

Here is how I preprocess the data in C++:

```
vector<Mat> detected_objects;

//extract the object ROI
Mat image_roi = img_orig(roi);

detected_objects.push_back(image_roi);
```

and how I make batch predictions in C++:

```
if (detected_objects.size() > 0) {

vector<Mat> preds;
    
Mat inputBlobs = cv::dnn::blobFromImages(detected_objects, 1.0, Size(224, 224));
    
net.setInput(inputBlobs);
Mat outputs = net.forward();

}
```

It seems that I am not preprocessing the image the right way in C++ and therefore I am not getting the same results. But I cannot find a equivalent for the Keras preprocess_input() method in C++.

Looking at the Keras documentation the python preprocess_input() method scale the data between 1 and -1. So I do not know if I should normalize the data using the cv::normalize method or do something with the blobFromImages scale factor. I am a bit confused here.

Could you please tell me what I should do to preprocess the data the same way in C++ even if it is not through Keras which does not seem to be available in C++.

Comment: Seems all it does in source is `x /= 127.5`, `x -= 1`, `return x`. Setting `scalefactor = 1/127.5` and `mean = Scalar(1, 1, 1)` in `blobFromImages` should work. You might also need to set appropriate `swapRB` value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your time, I will give it a try. What I did my end is that I preprocessed the image with the opencv `normalize(image_roi, image_roi, -1, 1, NORM_MINMAX);`to make sure I do the same thing than the Keras preprocess_input method. And finally I changed the parameters in the OpenCV blobFromImages method: `Mat inputBlobs = cv::dnn::blobFromImages(detected_objects, 1.0, Size(224, 224), true);//swapRB true BGR -> RGB ` Do you agree with the process?